# javascript function is undefined only in ie

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have a site.html page which include 3 .js files, the scripts runs, prepares the enviroment and extrects another m.html file out of an .xml file and present this generated m.html file on the screen using the folwing code:

```
var dd=document.open("text/html","replace");
dd.write(htmlData);
dd.close();
```

the site.html looks like this:

```
    <html>
    <head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="file1.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="file2.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="file3.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file4.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    _
    </body>
    </html>
```

the generated m.html which looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file4.css">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="uag.js"></script>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head> 
<body id="homebody">
<img class="background" src="a.jpg">
<div id="homebuttons">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<a href="javascript:alert(typeof PL_open)"><img src="b.png"></a>
</td>

<td class="spacer">
</td>
<td>
<a href="javascript:PL_open('activate:a')"><img src="c.png"></a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="spacer">
</tr>
<tr>

<td>
<a href="javascript:PL_open('activate:b')"><img src="d.png"></a>
</td>
<td class="spacer">
</td>
<td>
<a href="javascript:PL_open('activate:c')"><img src="e.png"></a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

is presented correctly but when I'm pressing one of the buttons (links) I get the error message:
object expected: JScript - window script block, line 1, char 1.

if I press the first link I get the text "undefined" in the alert box.

The PL_open() js function is defined in file1.js and according to tests is defined until the m.html is loaded to screen.

The exect same code works perfectly in chrome and safary.

Can anyone point or guide me to the problem? I'll be grateful for any kind of help! my brain is already melted :)
Thanks a lot in advence!

**Edit:**

Thanks for your comments!! I deleted the quote by mistake when posting the question so the problem is not "missing single quote".

I made a test and included file1.js in m.html. in this case the function runs but as expected it enters an endless loop. so I think the file.js and uag.js are ok. I can post them anyway if necessary. and about using ajax... can you explain more? I would like to try it.

Comment: missing a single quote in your generated html: `<a href="javascript:PL_open('activate:a)"><img src="c.png"></a>`

Comment: try using ajax instead of document.open

Comment: Can you post the code of "file1.js" and "uag.js"? Maybe there is the issue....

Comment: One thing that often causes problems with IE is if you add an additional comma to the end of an object literal e.g. 

var foo = { thing:'hello', otherthing: 'blah',}

That last comma may cause the javascript to fail silently on IE

Comment: Thanks for you replys!! I deleted the quote by mistake when posting the question so the problem is not "missing single quote".

Comment: I made a test and included file1.js in m.html. in this case the function runs but as expected it enters an endless loop. so I think the file.js and uag.js are ok. I can post them anyway if necessary. and about using ajax... can you explain more? I would like to try it.

Comment: Ajax would be useful in this case: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Just a tip - it would be easier for us to analyze your code if you would make a working jsfiddle.net project with mentioned issue and paste the link here.

Comment: Arrow functions (`=>`) can also be a source of problems with older versions of IE. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56841207/5802289

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm using ajax to change the body of the document (instead of document.open) and now it is working :)
Thank you d4rkpr1nc3 for the advice!
I'm still not sure about why ie doesn't recognize the function, but this solution is good.