# Get undefined javascript function in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, internet-explorer-11

I got some error when call function in IE 11. In my case I have two scripts inside one `<script>` tag.

This is my function :

```
<script>
function test()
{
    alert("oke");
    var currency = $('#curr_drop').val();
    var total_room_qty = calculate_amount(currency); // total all room

    var btn_class = $('#book_button').prop('class');

    var this_qty = $(this).val();
    var this_plan_type = $(this).data('plan-type');
    var this_plan_id = $(this).data('plan-id');
    var this_plan_day = $(this).data('plan-day');
}

function calculate_amount(currency = 'IDR') 
{
    //alert("ok");
    var nights = $('[name="nights"]').val();
    var total_amount = 0; var total_room_qty = 0; var total_qty_room_id = 0;

    console.log('nights: '+nights);


    return total_room_qty;
}
</script>
```

I call that `test` function from this code :

```
<select name="qty" class="mb10" onchange="test.bind(this)()" data-plan-type="rate" data-plan-id="38" data-plan-day="52459">
   <option value="0">0 rooms</option>
   <option value="1">1 rooms</option>
   <option value="2">2 rooms</option>
   <option value="3">3 rooms</option>
   <option value="4">4 rooms</option>
   <option value="5">5 rooms</option>
</select>
```

My problem is when I tried to show `alert` in top of function `test` I got `undefined function test` but if I close `var total_room_qty = calculate_amount(currency); // total all room` the alert can be shown in IE 11 browser. How it could be happen and how to I fix this ? Thanks

Comment: Is the script tag after the select in page?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani I put that script in bottom of my page before close `body` tag

Comment: That's the problem then, change the order and it will work

Comment: @PatrickHund what do you mean change the order ? Can you explain to me ?

Comment: First the script tag, then the select element. Sorry, I'm on my phone, don't have time to write proper answer

Comment: @MehdiDehghani could you give me some example with `window.test = function () { ... }` ?

Comment: `function calculate_amount(currency = 'IDR')` - will break Internet Exploder every day of the week

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function declaration for calculate_amount is wrong.  You are trying to use es6 in ie11.

```
function calculate_amount(currency = 'IDR') // this will work only in chrome and firefox
```

Unfortunately IE didn't throw an error. That is the reason your event handler is not reachable.

change it to

```
function calculate_amount(currency) 
{
    currency = currency || 'IDR'; //if your intent is to set a default value for currency
    //alert("ok");
    var nights = $('[name="nights"]').val();
    var total_amount = 0; var total_room_qty = 0; var total_qty_room_id = 0;

    console.log('nights: '+nights);


    return total_room_qty;
}
```

example 
https://jsfiddle.net/karthick6891/0681reux/

Comment: Such a stupid problem to have!! Answer saved my bacon thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was also having a similar error and Google brought me here.

In my case, it was also a syntax incompatibility problem with older versions of IE: the use of [arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900875/whats-the-meaning-of-an-arrow-formed-from-equals-greater-than-in-javas) (`=>`) is not supported.

In order to solve it, see [Syntax error in IE using ES6 arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40110022/syntax-error-in-ie-using-es6-arrow-functions).

Unfortunately, IE was telling me that the function below this expression was undefined, so it took a while to find out what was the actual error.

I hope this can save time to others with the same problem.